# jQuery After restart, no longer react to click

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to implement a bouncing ball where it has 2 properties:
1. Random color change
2. Upon clicking on it, the speed increases.At the maximum speed, a message appear and click on it to reset the speed back to default.

I managed to implement the random color change on my own. For the message, I realise when I reach the maximum speed, I click on the message to reset the speed. After that, the ball no longer reach to click to increase the speed. Does anyone has any idea why is it so?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exe7.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#ball").css("background", '#' + changeColor());
        },500); 
        var number = 12;
        $("#ball").click(function(){
            number = number -1 ;
            $(this).css('animation-duration', number + 's');

            if (number == 0) {
                $(this).css('animation-duration', '1s');
                $('#message').text('Maximum speed! Click here to restart!');
                $("#message").click(function(){
                    $("#ball").css('animation-duration', '12s');
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function changeColor(){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ball"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `setInterval` of 500 milliseconds is completely overriding the 12 Seconds intended duration time. Change this to `12000` to match the `animation-duration` https://jsfiddle.net/6n4sp8r4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reset the number value = 12 after condition of number = 0

```
    if (number == 0) {
                    $(this).css('animation-duration', '1s');

                    $('#message').text('Maximum speed! Click here to restart!');
                    $("#message").click(function(){
                        $("#ball").css('animation-duration', '12s');
**number=12;**
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I got stuck playing around with your code a bit I thought I'd at least post my snippet. What Parveen mentioned is correct though (reset the `number` variable), but it still would not animate on Chrome (for example) since you left those browser specific styles out.

This should be working in all browsers. A few other minor changes too, mostly regarding the resetting of elements/values once the animation reached it's end:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#ball").css("background", '#' + changeColor());
  }, 500);
  var number = 12;
  $("#ball").text(number).click(function() {
    number = number - 1;
    if (number > 0) setAnimCss(number);
    if (number == 0) {
      $('#message').text('Maximum speed! Click here to restart!');
      $("#message").click(function() {
        number = 12;
        $('#message').text('');
        setAnimCss(number);
      });
    }
  });
});

function changeColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}

function setAnimCss(seconds) {
  $("#ball").css({
    'animation-duration': seconds + 's',
    '-webkit-animation-duration': seconds + 's',
    '-moz-animation-duration': seconds + 's',
    '-o-animation-duration': seconds + 's'
  }).text(seconds);
}
```

```css
#message {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
#ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  top: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: moveY linear 0s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: moveY linear 0s infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: moveY linear 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: moveY linear 0s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 12s;
  -o-animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveY {
  from {
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveY {
  from {
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes moveY {
  from {
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes moveY {
  from {
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ball"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
```